# I don't see the added cookie. And it is not sent to the server

Tags: angular, cookies, session-cookies, c#-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I add a cookie and expect it to come in requests. But I don't see it in the browser, and it doesn't come back in requests.

The client side uses the latest version of angular. Post type request. **Do I understand correctly that cookies should be added automatically** ?

On server side i add it as follows:

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, data, new CookieOptions
        {
            Secure = True,
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            Path = "/",
            IsEssential = true,
        });
```

After requesting the server I see the set-cookie command in the header:
[image: s]

But I don't see the cookie itself (although the browser indicates that there is 1 cookie).

[image: dont see the cookie]

Also i don't see a cookie being sent with a request
[image: dont see the cookie]

**UPD**: Also tried SameSite=Lax + Secure=false. The cookie is not saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting `SameSite=None` without the `Secure` attribute with the `Secure = false` in your configuration. A cookie with `SameSite=None` must include `Secure`.

If you open Chrome DeveloperTools and look at the Issues tab you should be able to see more information about the cookie that has problems and what to do to address it. Your second screenshot is actually showing that your site is using `LocalStorage` not a cookie.

- There's background information here: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/
- Debugging information here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug
- Video version here: https://youtu.be/Fet6-IiX69E?t=516

Comment: Do I need to specify the "Unspecified" mode? Or "Lax" ?

Comment: I would try `Lax` first to see if that works. If you **need** a cross-site cookie then you need `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. It's always better to specify a value so that you get consistent behaviour across browsers.

Comment: UPATE: SameSite=None and Secure not working. The cookie is not saved. Also tried SameSite=Lax + Secure=false

Comment: Have you verified what is being sent in the `Set-Cookie` header in the responses? The Issues tab as described in the debugging guide will really help you here.

Comment: When client request "/version" url i see this in Response Header:
"Set-Cookie: MyCookie=data...; expires=Thu, 05 Sep 2030 15:31:22 GMT; max-age=315360000; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly"

After that, I don't see this cookie in the list in the Application Tab. Maybe it's because I need to specify the domain of the cookie when creating it ?

Also. In "Issues tab" i dont see problems with this cookie. i see other 27 issues but not with this cookie.

Comment: What do you see on https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me/ - Are all the rows showing a green ✔️? What's in the Application tab for this? e.g. should look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpDRNnxxD7GQQBp5OoqHQOwj4O1EkR9W/view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221136/discussion-between-michael-zagorski-and-rowan-m).